# Memory Leak in NSString+URLEncoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I ran the instruments in my app and saw some memory leaks in a category for NSString, NSString+URLEncoding:

```
- (NSString *)urlEncodedString {

    return (__bridge NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                        (__bridge CFStringRef)self,
                                                                        NULL,
                                                                        (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
                                                                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
}

- (NSString *)urlDecodedString {

    return (__bridge NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NULL,
                                                                                        (__bridge CFStringRef)self,
                                                                                        (CFStringRef)@"",
                                                                                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
}.
```

I'm using ARC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edgar, see Evernote's implementation for NSString+URLEncoding [available in GitHub here](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-ios/blob/master/evernote-sdk-ios/3rdParty/NSString%2BURLEncoding/NSString%2BURLEncoding.m).

You should use `__bridge_transfer` if you want ARC to release the object for you.

If you still want to maintain `__bridge` you must release the object manually.